I ask to my girlfriend to marry me and paid the mehr. She said qubool he three times. Is the nikah valid?
I ask to my girlfriend that me s/o my father with haq mehr 100. do you accept me. She said qubool he three times. Same from my side. She asked me n i said qubool he three times. And i paid haq mehr cash. Did nikah happen?
